# How to obtain the math.SE network whose edges are linked questions?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, linked-questions

> *Q*: What is the best way to obtain the math.SE network whose edges are linked questions?

I.e., the network whose nodes are the

[image: 318,363 questions]

on the site and we have an undirected edge from node A to node B whenever A links to B?

---

An example of what we see when a question is linked to another question:

[image: An example of a linked question]

and the linked question is linked back (hence undirected edges).

This is mostly out of curiosity: it would be interesting to see how this network is evolving over time.

Comment: This is a great question, and I think I'm going to see if maybe I can do something with this.

Comment: Oh, but I didn't answer your question. This data is all in the SO data dumps - you just have to sift through it well enough. This information is also on the site itself, but following those links too quickly would perturb people, I think.

Comment: By the way, the edges are directed internally (in PostLinks table): question with PostId is the one that contains a link to question with RelatedPostId. When rendering the sidebar, the system looks up both directions.

Answer (score 15):

The data is contained in the PostLinks table, accessible through Data Explorer. I wrote a simple query [Post Links](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/221664/post-links?MinId=1&MaxId=500000). Since the table has more than $50000$ rows, it cannot be retrieved by SEDE at once. But one can limit the query by MinId, MaxId, download and merge the results. I think two tries will be enough: the query succeeds with `MinId=1` and `MaxId=500000`, another grab with `MinId=500001` and `MaxId=1000000` should do the job.

You can also download the data dump, as mixedmath said; though the Data Explorer is more up to date.

#### SEDE bug

Unfortunately, right now you can't download the results of the above query as CSV file: this is a [bug that will be squashed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234239/) with the next redeploy of SEDE.

Fortunately, the bug affects only the queries with parameters. Using the queries

- [Post Links by PostId ascending](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/221665/post-links-by-postid-ascending)
- [Post Links by PostId descending](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/221666/post-links-by-postid-descending)

one can get all the links. In fact, the first one gets almost all the results; only a relatively small piece of the second CSV file needs to be added to it.

#### Most linked questions

I don't expect the graph of linked questions to have interesting structure: it probably consists of a large number of small components, most of which are two-vertex components. It is of some interest to see which questions are linked most often, but [the site already shows that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent).

The current record is [$105$ links](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30732), held by [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30732/).