# What are the hottest sinks on Mathematics SE?

Tags: discussion, statistics, data-explorer, linked-questions

Consider the **directed graph** in which nodes are questions on Mathematics SE and (directed) edges are links from one question to another question.

What questions have the highest in-degree? Can one find that out? If so, how?

---

Possible duplicate:

- [How to obtain the math.SE network whose edges are linked questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16697/339790)

Comment: If the information is available with the API, and the access time is reasonably fast, someone should be able to write a program to figure it out.

Comment: @MattSamuel SEDE contains the table PostLinks which seems to be exatcly about links between posts: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677). So I guess that numbers could be found out from there. (Although I am not sure whether the links were added to this table already from the start of the site.)

Comment: I mean something like this: [Posts with most links to them - counting also links from answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1303133/posts-with-most-links-to-them-counting-also-links-from-answers) or [Posts with most links to them - only counting links from questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1303134/posts-with-most-links-to-them-only-counting-links-from-questions). (There are probably many various ways how to refine those queries.)

Comment: @amWhy Not quite. I asked about directed edges.

Comment: This answer explains some details about the PostLinks table: [What is the meaning of postlinks table?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226837#226840) According to that answer, PostLinks also includes links from the comments - I am not sure whether you wanted to count those, too. (And for questions, the links in answers are included, too.) Assuming the information given there is accurate, I have misunderstood that table a bit. (And I do not see an immediate way to count links *only from questions* - not including answers and comments.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you. I would be happy to rephrase my question. Nodes would be pages. A page consists of a question and perhaps some answers and comments. A comment that says "this question is a duplicate of this other question" is very useful to me.